# Cargo is unable to find a crate

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I have the following directory structure in my Rust project:

```
borrowing
   |
   |-------src
   |        |-------borrow.rs
   |        |-------lib.rs
   | 
   |-------Cargo.toml
   |-------main.rs
```

**borrow.rs**

```
pub fn simple_borrow() {
    let _a = 10;
    let _b = 20;
    let _b = _a;
    println!("a:{}, b: {}", _a, _b);
}
```

**lib.rs**

```
mod borrow;
```

**main.rs**

```
use borrow;

fn main()
{
    borrow::simple_borrow();
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "borrower"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]

[[bin]]
name="borrowery"
path="main.rs"
```

**The above is giving me the following error:**

```
C:\git\Rust examples\borrowing>cargo run
   Compiling borrower v0.1.0 (C:\git\Rust examples\borrowing)
warning: function `simple_borrow` is never used
 --> src\borrow.rs:1:8
  |
1 | pub fn simple_borrow() {
  |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(dead_code)]` on by default

warning: `borrower` (lib) generated 1 warning
error[E0432]: unresolved import `borrow`
 --> main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use borrow;
  |     ^^^^^^ no external crate `borrow`
  |
help: consider importing one of these items instead
  |
1 | use core::borrow;
  |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 | use std::borrow;
  |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `borrower` due to previous error

C:\git\Rust examples\borrowing>
```

**How can I resolve the error?**

Comment: The package name of library is `borrower`, and the borrow is not defined public, if you define it as `pub borrow` then you can use it in your main.rs like this: `use borrower::borrow;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has 2 errors, the first is you're using the wrong path for the module, `src/lib.rs` and every binary, in your case `main.rs` are in different crates, therefore instead of the relative path `borrow` you have to use the full path, including the crate name, which defaults to the packages name: `borrower::borrow`:

```rust
use borrower::borrow;
```

Then Rust will tell you that the module `borrow` is private and you can't use it. To make it public you can simply use the `pub` keyword in front of the module declaration in `src/lib.rs`:

```rust
pub mod borrow;
```